# Do textboxes consider pressing the enter key as submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, enter

Do all textboxes ( `<input type="text"` ) consider **"PRESSING THE ENTER KEY"** as submit action?

IF yes, do all browser supports this?

If no, the what's wrong with my code detecting the enter key on press?

```
$('#quick-search-input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
  if ( e.keyCode === 13 || $('#the-button').val() ) {
     alert("pressed");
  }
});
```

This code alerts on all key presses, not only on enter. Something must be wrong. I'm using jquery 1.4 BTW and don't ask why. Can't upgrade for now.

Comment: Your code says: whenever `enter` is pressed OR the button has a value, alert me with the 'pressed' message. What you want to have, is just the e.keyCode part to check for an enter. Then, when enter is pressed, you should validate your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

you are checking if pressed key is eneter or textbox has value if any of condition is true than if condition will work

```
if ( e.keyCode === 13 || $('#the-button').val() ) {
```

---

Change it to

```
if ( e.keyCode === 13) {
   alert("Enter Pressed");
}
```

---

If you want value should not be empty than

```
if ( e.keyCode === 13 && $.trim($('#the-button').val()) !== '') {
   alert("Enter Pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes in your code logic,

```
$('#quick-search-input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
  if ( e.keyCode === 13 && $('#the-button').val()!="" ) {
     alert("pressed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will better to use e.which instead of e.keyCode as per  [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)